# Java interface to C library - Refactoring to singleton usage

Tags: java, api, singleton

I am currently writing a Java interface to a C library. It mostly just delegates calls and adds a object oriented layer on top of it to make integration into a regular Java program more natural.

The C library talks to a (local) server which in turn communicates with a real device.

My current design uses dependency injection and a central `Connection` class which provides access to the lower level C API binding (I use JNA). It looks like this:

```
public class Connection {
    public void connect(int port);
    public APIBinding getBinding();
}

public interface DataReceiver {
    public Data getData();
}

public class DeviceDataReceiver implements DataReceiver {
    public DeviceDataReceiver(Connection conn);
    public Data getData(); // Use conn.getBinding() to retrieve Data package
}

public class FileDataReceiver implements DataReceiver {
    public FileDataReceiver(File file);
    public Data getData(); // Load data from file, for device simulation
}
```

I think this is quite solid, as it provides the user with the opportunity to run a program with the `FileDataReceiver` instead of the `DeviceDataReceiver`, so that they can use pre-recorded data.

But there is one thing bugging me - There can actually only be one instance of every `Device` dependant class. Creating multiple instances would only result in confusing behavior, since there is only one state, which is held inside the C library. The imperative nature of the C library doesn't translate to the object oriented nature of my Java API.

I want to solve this by making my device dependant classes singletons. Personally I dislike singletons, but the usage of the API would get a lot more intuitive.

My main problem is how to name my singleton classes and how to access them in a way that doesn't feel awkward for the user. My first approach was this:

```
public class Device {
    // Handles the single instance problem
    // The old classes stay the same
    public static ConnectionManager getConnectionManager();
    public static DataReceiver getDataReceiver();
    ...
}

// Using it like this:
Device.getConnectionManager().connect(1234);
DataReceiver dr = Device.getDataReceiver();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(dr.getData());
}
```

There are two things that I am not sure about with this solution:

1. Is `Manager` a good name? It feels very generic.
2. The single instance management is done by my `Device` class. Normally you have something like `Connection.INSTANCE` and a private constructor. While being more restrictive, this approach also would make my classes pretty much untestable, as I have to inject a mock of the JNA binding. Is using `Device` as a instance-manager a good approach to circumvent that problem?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review and good job on your first post; could you please update the title to reflect the purpose of the code, instead of one particular question you have; apart from that you should get some good answers!

Comment: Thank you, I hope the updated title does fit the question format on Codereview better.